# Calculate Permutations of a given string - 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python

My code works for a list of length 2 but for anything more I get 'NoneType' object is not iterable.  I am new to python and just finished the crash course so any help would be appreciated.

```
def permutation(list1):
    if len(list1) == 0:
        print("There are no permuations.")

    elif len(list1) == 1:
        return[list1]

    else:
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            newlist = list1[1:]
            for perm in permutation(newlist):
                perm.insert(i,list1[0])
            print(perm)
```

so for a list of `[a,b]` I get `[a,b],[b,a]`.
but when i try `[a,b,c]` i get nonetype error and I'm unsure why.

Comment: for permutation use `from itertools import permutations`

Comment: Most of your branches don't return anything. You're trying to iterate over the results of `permutation(newlist)`, but how do you expect that to work if `permutation` doesn't return a value (in particular, a list)?

Comment: `permutation` returns `None` unless the list has exactly 1 item.

Comment: I never added a return function for the length greater than one and I didn't add them to a list.... Sorry I'm new at this thanks for the help